# Why madara did not change after 1 and 8 tails was extracted from him?

Tags: naruto

Obito extracted Shukaku and eight tails from Madara and gave it to Naruto. Then why did madara not return back to normal?

Why was he still able to cast infinite tsukoyomi?

Comment: Shukaku is Ichibi (1 Tail). Please verify whether you mean 1 tail or the 2 tails Matatabi.

Comment: @AyaseEri Done. But that's not important.

Comment: @AyaseEri any answer???

Comment: Patience, young padawan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Wiki,

> Obito stabs Madara and manages to steal fragments of the One-Tail's and Eight-Tails' chakra from him before using Kamui to escape with Naruto.

Obito only took a small fragment, not the entire beast.

ref: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha